# How to copy build artifact to external server in Teamcity?

Tags: deployment, teamcity

I am working on Angular 4 deployment using TeamCity. I need to copy artifacts generated by build to a external FTP-server in automated manner. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a specific Build Step with the runner type: `FTP Upload`

You should use it either:

- After producing the content to push.
- In another build step, with artifact dependencies.